# Calculate mean() of Nympy 2D-array grouped by values in a separate list with strings corresponding to each row in the 2D array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm attending a course on Data Analysis with Python (Numpy, Pandas etc).

We have an assignment where we are supposed to calculate mean() of an array - based on values of another list.
This might seem a bit unclear so here's an example:

```
list = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']
array = [ [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
        [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
        [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
        [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
        [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
        [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
        [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
        [5. , 3.4, 1.5, 0.2] ]
```

The list-values corresponds to categories for the rows in the array and we are asked to calculate the mean of each column grouped by A and B.
I suppose this could be done by converting the data into a Pandas dataframe - but the assignment pertains to Numpy so i suppose we are somehow supposed to solve it without Pandas.

I have struggled and googled to no avail.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

B.R.
Anders

Comment: I think it would be better if you showed us what you have tried so far

Comment: Did you find one of the answers below suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way I can think of is to split the rows and compute the mean. However, this approach is a quick cheat and falls short if you want to generalize your solution to different forms for `list`:

```
>>> [x.mean() for x in np.split(np.array(array), 2)]
[2.40625, 2.58750]
```

---

A more appropriate solution is to prepare a dictionary of categories. Then sequentially append the rows to the correct entry in the map. I have renamed `list` to `keys`.

```
>>> res = {k: [] for k in set(keys)}
{'A': [], 'B': []}

>>> for k, row in zip(keys, array):
...     res[k] += row

>>> res
{'A': [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
 'B': [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4, 4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3, 5.0, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2]}
```

Then compute the means:

```
>>> [(k, sum(v)/len(v)) for k, v in res.items()]
[('B', 2.5875), ('A', 2.40625)]
```

This will work for any number of categories, and any form of category sequence `keys`. So long as `len(keys)` is equal to the number of rows.

---

I am sure you can come up with a full NumPy alternative yourself.

Comment: please explain the rules for find the mean.  how are the labels associated to the rows.   is the mean the groupby of the labels?

Comment: `res` is *dict* mapping each labels to an array of floats, it's basically a *grouped-by* version of `array`. From there you can iterate over each value and compute the mean as `sum/length` of each grouped array.

Comment: Hi all - I've marked this post as answer. (though the post below also solves the problem) The dict-method is very elegant and prefer this. Would never have thought of this trick myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
import numpy as np

list = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']
array = np.array([ [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
        [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
        [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
        [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
        [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
        [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
        [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
        [5. , 3.4, 1.5, 0.2] ])
        
idxA = np.array([i for i, x in enumerate(list) if x == "A"])
idxB = np.array([i for i, x in enumerate(list) if x == "B"])

print(np.mean(array[idxA]))
print(np.mean(array[idxB]))
```

Output:

```
2.40625
2.5875000000000004
```

Comment: Hi Roland - your suggestion also solves my problem but regretfully I cant mark two replies as answer. Thank you so much for the feed back.

Comment: enumerate returns a index,value tuple.  Your using the index value of list to access values in array then finding the average.